# How to mount a device to a cluster, not an individual host with Ansible module

Tags: ansible

I have a cluster of ESXi hosts and want to mount a device (LUN/Volume) and create a datastore, and then present it to the whole cluster, not an individual ESXi host.

I know for datastore creating there is a module named "vmware_host_datastore" in which you must specify the ESXi hostname like below:

```
- name: Mount VMFS datastores to ESXi
  vmware_host_datastore:
      hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
      username: '{{ vcenter_user }}'
      password: '{{ vcenter_pass }}'
      datacenter_name: '{{ datacenter }}'
      datastore_name: '{{ item.name }}'
      datastore_type: '{{ item.type }}'
      vmfs_device_name: 'naa.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
      vmfs_version: 6
      esxi_hostname: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      state: present
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Is there a way to create and mount it to a cluster by using this module or another one?

How to mount a device to a cluster not an individual host on VMWare with Ansible module

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research and found my answer (which could be due to a lack of proper VMWare knowledge.)

For whoever interested:

When you are creating a datastore on VMWare, while you are mounting an unmounted volume which you have just created, you have to choose a host from that cluster. Ultimately it's gonna mount the datastore to a specific host, but it's gonna be shared between all hosts in that cluster and that's what we want.
So the conclusion is that Ansible doesn't have any module to mount a device to a cluster instead of an individual host, and that's not even required. 
You can just use the vmware_host_datastore module and do this.

Nevertheless, as the `vmware_host_datastore` module can be used to create datastores from local ou shared devices, when mounting a datastore to a host one can only choose from hosts that can actually access the underlying device.